How to know what sends a broadcast packet on port 8765
While looking at the traffic on Wireshark, I noticed my computer was sending a UDP packet every three seconds on the broadcast address to the port 8765, with the content "*" (42 in ASCII). It doesn't seem to be a response to anything. The source port changes every packet.
I tried to nail down what was emitting this packet to no avail. I tried:

Stopping all of the non-vital services I could think of.
Add an iptables rule to drop the packets (this stop the packets, but doesn't help me knowing what emits them).
Add an iptables rule to stop forwarding to see if somehow it was forwarded by my computer, but no.
Use auditd with various parameters, but nothing matched and I couldn't even find a write(*,*,1)/send(*,*,1)/sendto(*,*,1,*,*)/sendmsg/sendmmsg with the right frequency. I am however not familiar with auditd.

auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S socket -F a0=2 -F a1=2 to search for creation of IPv4 UDP sockets.
auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S connect just to look for any connections.
auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S write -S send -S sendto -F a2=1 to match send and write syscalls with length of 1.
audictl  -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S sendmsg -S sendmmsg
All of the above with -F arch=b32 instead.


Use netstat/ss but the socket is probably very short lived so it doesn't show anything.

What are other ways to pin down what transmit this packet? What if it comes from the kernel or a kernel module? How could I know?

Many ways to do this.
I tend to just use bpftrace, copy one of the scripts from /usr/share/bpftrace/tools, e.g., killsnoop.bt, and replace the tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_kill  with the according syscalls, sys_enter_sendmsg and …_sendmmsg.
Then it becomes something like this
#!/usr/bin/env bpftrace
BEGIN
{
    printf("Tracing sendto(x, x, 1, x, x) signals... Hit Ctrl-C to end.\n");
    printf("%-9s %-6s %-16s\n", "TIME", "PID", "COMM");
}

tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_sendto
{
    if (args->len == 1)
    {
        time("%H:%M:%S  ");
        printf("%-6d %-16s\n", pid, comm);
    }
}

which will at least list all the calls to sendmsg and variants in real time, which probably suffices to identify who does what.
If there's no syscalls that send messages, chances are this is a kernel thread – are you perhaps doing wireguard, SMB/CIFS, NFS/sunrpc in the kernel and have forgotten about it? Big candidate, also: questionable "endpoint security" kernel modules from questionable antivirus vendors.

Thanks! I got it using bpftrace. I don't know how I missed it using auditd. It was an old iceccd setup, from the icecream distributed compiler.
Just for completeness, bpftrace (or at least my version) has pid as a standalone variable, not in args.

@Hugal31 great to hear it worked out! You could replace my untested script with your working one, if you want, as a service to future readers.

Are there non-questionable commercial antivirus vendors? I've had major issues with all solutions my organization has deployed. ☺️

@doneal24 I didn't mean to imply there were :)
